# How to set default params for data which comes from server?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I send a GET request and in response get a user object like this:

```
{
  name: 'Alex',
  email: 'test@test.com',
  age: 18,
}
```

then I need to set this object to the state and render data in some different components

```
interface User {
  name: string | null,
  email: string,
  age: number,
}

const [user, setUser] = useState<User>();

const getUser = async () => {
  const response = await API.getUserData();
  setUser(response);
} catch (error) {
  console.log(error)
}
```

The problem:
For some reason name might be null and in this case I should render on a page default values. As far as I know it can be done in many ways. The most obvious one is with conditional statements like this:

```
<h1>{name ? name : 'Default value'}</h1>

or

<h1>{name ?? 'Default value'}</h1>
```

But for me its a bad option because too many conditions in many components. Is there a way to set a default values in getUser function? Eventually I want to have my components to be
like this:

```
// if name is null then its equal to some default value otherwise it equals to the value from server.
<h1>{name}</h1>
```

Comment: Your type argument says `user` can never not have a user object, but you're initializing it with `undefined` (by not providing an argument to `useState`). Are you going to handle the case where `user` is `undefined`? If so, you need to update your type argument (to `<User | undefiend>`, or you might use `null` and pass `null` as the argument to `useState`).

Answer (score 0):

I think one option is transforming response before you invoke `setUser`. Something like this

```js
function transformUserData(userData) {
  // make transformation and replacement on Default Values
}
```

```js
const getUser = async () => {
  const response = await API.getUserData();
  const responseWithDefaultValues = transformUserData(response);

  setUser(responseWithDefaultValues);
} catch (error) {
  console.log(error)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can set your default values in `useState`:

```
const [user, setUser] = setState<User>({
  name: "default value",
  email: "default email address",
  age: 0
})
```

Then with API calls, it gets changes.

But there is an issue if the API response was `{name: null}`, it's not back to default value. so you must destruct your `response` and check the values before `setUser`:

```
const getUser = async () => {
  const response = await API.getUserData();
  const {name, email, age} = response;
  setUser({name: name || "default value", email: email, age: age});
} catch (error) {
  console.log(error)
}
```

**as a side note:**

The proper syntax for short circuit is:

```
<div> {name && 'Default value'} </div>
```